# Orange Predictor Widget Error Message "Field7 Not In Domain"

Tags: python-3.x, orange

When I connect my scoring data and a classifier (classification tree) to the Orange Canvas Predictor Widget I get an error message "Field7 Not in Domain".  My scoring data does have a Field7, and the classification tree was trained with data that has a Field7, and also shows it uses Field7.  Both the Field7 in my data and in the training data I used to build the classifier are continuous.

What is the problem here, and how can I resolve it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the training and testing data should have matching domains, i.e., if you trained on data with X, Y, Z features, your testing or unlabeled data should also contain X, Y, Z features. Otherwise, how could the tree know which way to go?

[Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Orange's issue tracker](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues) might be somewhat more appropriate venues for this programming-unrelated question and you'll probably get more answers there.

Comment: K3---mc,  Thanks for your response.  I'm sure the feature in question is in both the classifier and data.  What I've found since I've posted the question is that some of the rows in the column in question are missing data.  I deleted them using the IMPUTE widget and that solved the problem.

Thanks also for the two links.  I've checked them out and they look like they'll be helpful to me in the future.